# Device location is null on another device (GoogleMaps Activity)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently working on my second android app which contains a google maps activity. In this activity I would like to show the user their current location. I kind of managed to do it and it works on both of my devices (Huawei P smart & Galaxy S5). I also sent my friend an APK of the app and on his device (Huawei P9 Lite) the current location returns null after calling task.getResult(). On his device the method will always jump to the else statement (meaning the currentLocation == null). I used the following method.

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    try {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location currentLocation) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                    if (currentLocation != null) {

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have tried/done the following things:

- Adding all required permissions/features to my manifest
- Trying some other solutions I found here, as far as I'm aware none of them were showing different results on different devices
- Changing the minSDK to 17 (was 23 before).
- Adding the nullcheck and try & catch

Because I'm having no problems on my own devices and can't find anything remarkable in my logcat's (since it's all working on my devices) it's kind of hard for me to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Maybe the location services is off in his phone?

Comment: For devices having Marshmallow and over dangerous permissions should be given runtime requests. check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: I have done this already. My app prompts the user to give permission for turning on the location services. His location permissions are off before running and the app turns them on correctly.

Comment: there is some types of location
make sure device location is on and it is set to High accuracy

Comment: He just checked it and it's on and on high accuracy.